# Errbit client for clojure (ring)

Tags: clojure, ring, airbrake, errbit

I tried [clj-airbrake](https://github.com/bmabey/clj-airbrake) but it doesn't seem to log errors in errbit. Is there any errbit client for clojure?

Answer (score 0):

errbit is designed to be compatible with the airbrake API, so this should work: https://github.com/bmabey/clj-airbrake